# Nodejs connection with mssql showing error

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am trying to connect with my sql server using nodejs, with the following code.

```
const sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
user: 'user',
password: 'psw',
server: 'localhost', 
database: 'sumit' 
};


var mssql = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
mssql.connect().then(function(){
var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
req.query("SELECT * from Category").then(function(res){
    console.table(res);
});
}).catch(function(err){
console.log(err);
})
```

but everytime it is showing

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not
>   connect (sequence)

how should i connect with my sql server?
i have tried to change config also

```
var config = {
  user: 'user',
  password: 'psw',
  server: 'DESKTOP-VVN4PRG\\SQLEXPRESS', 
  database: 'sumit' 
 };
```

but still getting same error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I resolved my problem. I am putting my answer here, So maybe it will help someone.

Step 1: Check if you have selected **SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode** on **Server Authentication** section

> **Path:** SMSS>Go to object explorer properties> Security(Check **SQL
>   Server and Windows Authentication mode**, if not, then check it)

Step 2: Check if you have TCP Port 1433 and TCP Dynamic Port is **Blank**(not **0**)

> **Path:** SQL Server Configuration Manager>SQL Server Network Configuration>Protocols for SQLEXPRESS> Double click on TCP/IP>IP
>   Addressess> Check for **IPALL** and for **127.0.0.1**

Step 3: If you have performed any of the above or both the operation then please restart all your SQL Services by going

> **Path:** Window + R> type **services.msc** and hit enter> Check for your SQL Services and restart all

Hope this would help someone.

Comment: For step 2, the default for TCP/IP protocol was disabled for me. Had to enable it.

Comment: @colinwurtz Hello by opening SQL Server Network Configuration in the Administrator mode you can enable the TCP\IP.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for more than 2 hours and finally landed on this solution to enable SQLBrowser and it worked like magic[image: enter link description here]

Comment: did u provided any link here?

Comment: Add the link please

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to do both things mentioned on the 2 answers above. I had to fix the IPALL on step 2 for answer 1.
And turn on the Sql Server Browser service too. Without this service the mssql would not connect.
This makes sense to me after read what this service does. Found this Microsoft article [How SQL Server Browser works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: The answer is a little unclear. Did you need to go to the IPALL section and set the TCP dynamic port to blank and the TCP port to 1433?